# Support for fixed-length fields

Tags: syntax-highlighting, syntax

I have a file which contains several lines. Each line contains of several "fields" (about 20 - 40 ), each having a fixed length of characters. There are no gaps (field1 follows fields2 and so on) and the field definition for every line is the same.

The field definition is given as a Word table.

As an example, field1 contains characters 1-4, field 2 characters 5-6, and so on.

Reading and writing such a file is very cumbersome: I always need to count characters and when I write, I Have to careful not to spill into the next field.

Does Emacs provide any means helping to read such a file (maybe color coding the fields or representing them in a table) and writing it?

Comment: Maybe [array mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ArrayMode)?